# Array.prototype.flat() creates an error when building Gatsby site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, flatten

When building, I get the following error:

```
WebpackError: TypeError: Object.entries(...).map(...).flat is not a function
```

I can `gatsby deveop` the app just fine, and all works as expected in the browser.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is ideal, but the only way I was able to fix this was by adding a polyfill and including it at the top of the offending file.

```
> yarn add array-flat-polyfill

// src/pages/page-with-error.js
import 'array-flat-polyfill';
```